Getting linking error while testing to add vulkan shaderc in my project
CMakeLists.txt
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE Vulkan::Vulkan)

in my shader.cpp
void OpenGLShader::Compile(const std::unordered_map<GLenum, std::string>& shaderSources)
    {       
        vk::Buffer;
        shaderc::Compiler compiler;
        shaderc::CompileOptions options;
    }

what iam try to do is testing if this works for shaderc but ima getting these error
out\build\x64-debug\GLContext.lib(OpenGLShader.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol shaderc_compiler_release referenced in function "public: __cdecl shaderc::Compiler::~Compiler(void)" (??1Compiler@shaderc@@QEAA@XZ)
out\build\x64-debug\GLContext.lib(OpenGLShader.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol shaderc_compile_options_initialize referenced in function "public: __cdecl shaderc::CompileOptions::CompileOptions(void)" (??0CompileOptions@shaderc@@QEAA@XZ)
\out\build\x64-debug\GLContext.lib(OpenGLShader.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol shaderc_compile_options_initialize referenced in function "public: __cdecl shaderc::CompileOptions::CompileOptions(void)" (??0CompileOptions@shaderc@@QEAA@XZ)
\out\build\x64-debug\GLContext.lib(OpenGLShader.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol shaderc_compile_options_release referenced in function "public: __cdecl shaderc::CompileOptions::~CompileOptions(void)" (??1CompileOptions@shaderc@@QEAA@XZ)


vk::Buffer;
this work fine but adding ```shaderc``` causes these errors can someone explain me what am i missing

This is usually the result of missing a library in the build. In this case it is probably the libraries associated with shaderc.

You mean to say the lib present in the vulkan folder that i may have missed, also i am just using Vulkan::Vulkan to link. Is there a similar alias for shaderc ?

Have a look at the cmake FindVulkan page. It mentions a shaderc_combined component. With it, you can find the package plus the component:
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED COMPONENTS shaderc_combined)

This will fill Vulkan_shaderc_combined_LIBRARY variable.
In my project I went on to change this one for debug, apparently something was off for me (so ymmv):
string(REPLACE ".lib" "d.lib" SHADERC_DEBUG ${Vulkan_shaderc_combined_LIBRARY})

Now it's just a matter of adding these to your target link libraries, like you did with Vulkan
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    debug ${SHADERC_DEBUG}
    optimized ${Vulkan_shaderc_combined_LIBRARY})

With all that said, the above mentioned cmake page also mentions Vulkan::shaderc_combined, so perhaps it's even sufficient to use
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE Vulkan::Vulkan Vulkan::shaderc_combined)

but I have not tested that.

Thanks men you method works i literally could my have figured this out my own also what else worked for me for a successful compile was this target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE vulkan-1 shaderc_shared) i added the vulkanSDK manually using env.cmake an used the above to link the library idk if that's a correct approach but it also worked.

Happy to help. Please accept the answer such that the question is not marked as unanswered.

btw do you know how do i add spriv iam alos getting the same error when i try to link the spriv cross target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE vulkan-1 shaderc_shared spirv-cross-core) getting the same error with spriv

The cmake page abouf vulkan at least doess not list spirv-cross-core. I don't know if it is part of the SPIRV-Tools they mention. The Khronos SPIRV-Cross repository has a section about linking to it. You need to use the repository as a submodule (or pull it as a third party dependency in whichever way your system does it) and then use the add_subdirectory command with this as an input.
